# how to pass variable to another js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pass a variable from  a.js file to b.js file.

a.js

```
var test='test string';
```

b.js

```
alert(test);
```

I am sure a.js is included in my html before b.js but I still got '`test`' is not defined error. Are there anyway to debug this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is the first line inside a callback? (eg inside, `$(document).ready`)

Comment: can you post a Short, Self Contained, Correct Example

Comment: Try declaring it as `test = 'test string';`, e.g. without the `var` !

Comment: Or explicitly as `window.test`, to make it apparent that it is a global (other readers of your code might thank you some day)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure test is assigned to the global scope, do:

```
window.test = 'test string';
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are as much passing a variable in this case as making it accessible. 
At some point you may want to look at [this (scope vs. context)](http://clubajax.org/javascript-scope-and-context-not-the-same-thing/). It may seem like a bit much this early on, but it will come in handy sooner than you think.

Answer (score 0):

To debug:

a.js:

```
var a = 'a';
console.log(b);
```

b.js:

```
var b = 'b';
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using top-down execution in your javascript files?  Using the global scope - unless its a constant or a helper function - its almost always a bad idea...

At a minimum, define functions if not classes and pass variables between those instead...